# Gas liquid transition

Tags: gas-laws

[image]

This is isotherm of a real gas is represented as shown in diagram at three temperature . In my book it is written that in ACIH gas liquid transition will involve only one phase throughout .

But I could not understand how this can be possible as at A it would be gas while at H it would be liquid .

Comment: What's unclear about that? Do you know what a [critical point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(thermodynamics)) is (and where is it on your picture, BTW)?

Comment: @IvanNeretin point F

Comment: Good. Then again, what's unclear? You have a field with a fence, and the fence is not infinite; it has an end somewhere far away. You want to get to the other side of the fence. To climb over it, or to walk around it, that's the question.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I mean at H ,I it will be liquid while at A ,C it will be gas . So in the book how they have written there is no phase transition.

Comment: They have written so because this is true. If you go A-D-E-G, you climb over the fence. If you go A-C-I-G, then you walk around the fence.

Comment: @IvanNeretin but in that there is phase change that is initially it was gas and latter it is liquid

Comment: So what? Again, it is good that you know _where_ is critical point, but do you know _what_ is it?

Comment: @IvanNeretin under that curve both liquid and gas exist

Comment: What curve? I thought we were talking about the critical point.

Comment: @IvanNeretin by curve I mean EFD . critical point is the point above which there is no phase change

Comment: Well, yeah, you may define it like that. Now what's the question? You walk around the critical point, and you get from gas to liquid without a phase transition.